# Do url shortening services shorten the id or directly the url?

Tags: url, url-shorteners

Assuming the urls are saved to a database where they each have id and the URL saved.

For example a URL `www.example.com` (let's say with id 1000) would possibly be shortened to `www.url.com/c1hd5` etc.

Is the URL `id=1000` shortened to `c1hd5` with base64 or similar or are the ids shortened?

The 566 id could be shortened like this: 1 = 1, 2 = 2, ... 9 = 9, 10 = a. The 1000 id would be *fE* if we used every possible letter from a-Z and - _.

Is it good idea to use ids from database to shorten urls?

Answer (score 4):

I would not assume that the id is present in the shortened URL at all. At the simplest level the shortening service is a simple lookup between the real URL and the shortened one, where the short form is either generated from some function (base64 sounds plausible) or even simply the next url in a list (unlikely)

There's no guarantee that:

> example.com/some-path/id=1000

and

> example.com/some-path/id=1001

will shorten to anything remotely similar.